# IOS store ipv6 rejected

Tags: ios, sockets, ipv6

When we upload a project written in **.net** Socket environment to iOS app store, we get the following rejection.

> We still discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

This is our client socket connection

```
Socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket.BeginConnect (ip, port, new AsyncCallback (ConnectionComplete), null);
```

Server connection code is this way

```
Socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket.Bind (new IPEndPoint (ip, port));
```

Because our game will be available on android and iOS platforms. So the server connection was made as **ipv4**. We are very grateful to you for your help in this matter. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an IP address or a DNS name in your app for your server. You should use a DNS name. Have you tested on an iov6 only network?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We're testing yours now.

Comment: You cannot connect an IPv6 client socket to an IPv4 server socket, but that is what you are attempting to do. The server needs to be listening on IPv6 in order to accept IPv6 clients.  Generally, you can create an IPv6 server socket that operates in dual-stack mode so it can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients.

Comment: Hello there. thanks for the answer. How do I create an IPv6 server socket that can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients?

Answer (score 1):

There is no error specific to IP v6. It's the generic message when app review fails because of server connection issues.

Apple uses IP v6 environment during the review process due to which they give the message about v6.

You should check and make sure the binary you have submitted on ITunes record for review process is able to make connection to your servers. Just check the methods used for HTTP connections.

Comment: We do not use HTTP. We use sockets.